# Cannot delete administrator user of shared drive with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently working with an account that has administrator privileges for a specific shared drive in GoogleDrive.
The account can manually add and remove other admin users.
I am able to add users from the GAS program but cannot remove other administrators.

There are two errors when deleting.

1. Error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.list failed with error: The requesting user does not have the administrator privileges required to access shared drive .
2. Failed to delete authority. :GoogleJsonResponseException: Failed to call drive.permissions.delete with the following error: File not found: role,,value, xxxxxxx@xxxxxx,type,domain

How would you like us to respond?
I would appreciate it if you could teach me.